# Need to enlarge the field box size

Tags: custom-fields

I've created some custom fields for a profile and would like one of them to have a larger text box than the default size.  How do I enlarge the field box size?

Answer (score 5):

I usually change the field type to be 'Note' when I need a longer length - then you specify length and number of lines - and it's expandable - if the user needs to add more they can resize the box.